# Connection reset by peer: socket write error docker

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker

i have tried to run mvn install dockerfile:build, howver the following exceptions popped up.
This is after turned on "Expose daemon to tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS”. Please help me with this matter. Also tried DOCKET_HOST=unix:///private/var/tmp/docker.sock. Nothing has changed.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment

```
C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment>mvn install dockerfile:build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.usermanagment.springboot:Usermanagment:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 77, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Usermanagment 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment\target\Usermanagment-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment\target\Usermanagment-1.0.jar to C:\Users\a-ggyarmat\.m2\repository\com\usermanagment\springboot\Usermanagment\1.0\Usermanagment-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment\pom.xml to C:\Users\a-ggyarmat\.m2\repository\com\usermanagment\springboot\Usermanagment\1.0\Usermanagment-1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.7:build (default-cli) @ Usermanagment ---
[INFO] Building Docker context C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment
[INFO]
[INFO] Image will be built as springio/Usermanagment:latest
[INFO]
Feb 21, 2018 7:13:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:2375: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[WARNING] An attempt failed, will retry 1 more times
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:185)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:105)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:246)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.propagate (DefaultDockerClient.java:2512)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request (DefaultDockerClient.java:2454)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1393)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1365)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:178)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:105)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:246)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue (AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get (AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get (AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request (DefaultDockerClient.java:2452)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1393)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1365)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:178)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:105)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:246)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:481)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run (ApacheConnector.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute (MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run (ClientRuntime.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run (ClientRuntime.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run (ApacheConnector.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute (MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run (ClientRuntime.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run (ClientRuntime.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run (ApacheConnector.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute (MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run (ClientRuntime.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run (ClientRuntime.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0 (Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite (SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write (SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite (SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer (SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write (SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.flushCacheWithAppend (ChunkedOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.write (ChunkedOutputStream.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write (CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write (WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.writeTo (ReaderWriter.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo (AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider.writeTo (InputStreamProvider.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider.writeTo (InputStreamProvider.java:60)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo (WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo (WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed (WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo (MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity (ClientRequest.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity (ClientRequest.java:499)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$2.writeTo (ApacheConnector.java:583)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo (RequestEntityProxy.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity (DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity (CPoolProxy.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest (HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute (HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run (ApacheConnector.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute (MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run (ClientRuntime.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run (ClientRuntime.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] Building Docker context C:\Users\ggyarmat\git\usermanagment\Usermanagment
[INFO]
[INFO] Image will be built as springio/Usermanagment:latest
[INFO]
Feb 21, 2018 7:13:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:2375: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.517 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-21T19:13:26+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 49M/508M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.7:build (default-cli) on project Usermanagment: Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: The same problem for me. Possibly this one can help https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/183, but it didn't help me

Answer (score 7):

This is happening because your target image name has a capital letter in it. `springio/Usermanagment:latest`

Please try with all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all images and containers, I had same issue, because was out of space.